# Removing javascript string last occurance string at the end of string

Tags: javascript

I have stringsuch as:

```
"<p>First sentence</p><p><br></p><p> second sentence</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>"
```

I want to remove all last occurrences of `<p><br></p>` from the string after `n` number of `<p>` tags.

Expected outcome:

```
"<p>First sentence</p><p><br></p><p> second sentence</p>"
```

Comment: First of all, please go read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/286047. And then [ask].

Comment: Take a look at RegExps.

Comment: So, you want to remove line breaks after second `p`?

Comment: Do you want to remove all the last ones (until that string no longer appears at the end) or have a parameter which is how many you want to remove and remove that many?

Comment: it could be after n number of p tag..but yes for this example it is second

Comment: @JoeIddon..yes I want to remove all the last ones...but not the one which are between content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"<p>First sentence</p><p><br></p><p> second sentence</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>".replace(/<p><br><\/p>?<p><br><\/p>/g,"")
```

easy,
pick me i am Answer

**Demo:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLzvYz

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex when you built-in DOM parser available to you.

You need to check if the element after current `p br` has an element with textContent or not.

```
function removeBlanksAtEnd(str) {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerHTML = str;
  console.log(el.querySelectorAll("p br").length);
  el.querySelectorAll("p br").forEach( s => {
     if ( !hasAnyContentAfterThisNode(s.parentNode) )
     {
        s.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(s.parentNode);
     }
  });
  return el.innerHTML;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = `<p>First sentence</p><p><br></p><p> second sentence</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>`;

function removeBlanksAtEnd(str) {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerHTML = str;
  console.log(el.querySelectorAll("p br").length);
  el.querySelectorAll("p br").forEach( s => {
     if ( !hasAnyContentAfterThisNode(s.parentNode) )
     {
        s.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(s.parentNode);
     }
  });
  return el.innerHTML;
}

function hasAnyContentAfterThisNode(el)
{
   while( el.nextSibling )
   {
      var textValue = el.nextSibling.textContent.trim();
      console.log(textValue);
      if ( textValue.length > 0 )
      {
          return true;
      }
      el = el.nextSibling;      
   }
   return false;
}

console.log(removeBlanksAtEnd(str));
```